# Install Gmagick on XAMPP (Mac OSX Yosemite)

Tags: php, xampp, osx-yosemite, gmagick

I'm using XAMPP version 5.6.3-0 on Mac OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite and I want to install the Gmagick (https://pecl.php.net/package/gmagick) extension which is the PHP API of graphicsmagic. (http://www.graphicsmagick.org)

So I downloaded gmagick and compiled it for php:

```
$ cd gmagick-1.1.7RC2
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.6.3
$ make
# sudo make install
```

Then I added this to the php.ini:

```
extension=gmagick.so
```

But the extension is not active. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasted too much time on xampp so I just used the built in Apache server that comes with Yosemite. This is how it worked:

Install Graphicsmagick:

```
$ brew install graphicsmagick
```

Download gmagick from: https://pecl.php.net/package/gmagick

Unzip it and do this:

```
$ cd gmagick-1.1.7RC2
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Edit the php.ini with

```
extension=gmagick.so
```

For further information on how to configure the built in apache server see this resource: http://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-multiple-php-versions

If you still have a solution to the problem with xampp, go ahead as it might be helpful to others. I'll keep xampp installed and test any suggestion.